# Check for counter-clockwise orientation instead of clockwise

Tags: c++, boost

I have a GeoJson polygon which gets mapped to a boost polygn using the following type for point and polygon:

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;
```

I'm facing an issue where I want to verify if the GeoJson Polygon is correctly oriented. For a GeoJson Feature this means: The exterior ring (shell) must be counter-clockwise, the interior rings (holes) must be clockwise. This is in contradiction to the checks done by boost, which verifies the exterior ring is oriented clockwise.

Is there a way to check for counter-clockwise orientation in both `geometry::is_valid` and `geometry::correct`?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the [`boost::geometry::model::polygon`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_polygon.html) class template, you'll find that the second template parameter is `ClockWise` which is `true` by default.

I suggest setting that to `false`:

```
using polygon_type = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type, false>;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Though, it looks like the orientation is used for both exterior and interior rings. For GeoJson the exterior ring must be ccw, while interior rings must be cw. In other polygons it's similarly the case that holes must be in the oppisite orientation. It doesn't look like this is covered in boost?

Comment: @benjist I see - and just filling the inner ring in the reverse order won't work?

Comment: It depends on the rendering engine, for example the web mapping sdk whether this is handled gracefully. In my case I‘m developing a backend system. I have no control over what frontend is used. As a workaround I could create two boost polygons for the shell and the holes with differing types. But this is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @benjist Odd. I just found this on `boost`'s page: "_If the polygons underlying ring_type is defined as clockwise, the exterior ring must have the clockwise orientation, and any interior ring must be reversed w.r.t. the defined orientation (so: counter clockwise for clockwise exterior rings). If the ring_type is defined counter clockwise, it is vice versa._" - That sounds just like what you want?

Comment: I'll give that a try. What's strange, though: Boost polygon's inner_container_type has elements of ring_type which get the the template param ClockWise. E.g., they will be initialized with the same ordering.

Comment: @benjist It may have the same name but are you sure it's really the same template parameter? If it is, I agree that it sounds fishy.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Not yet. I got a crash that I have to investigate.

Comment: @benjist Any news regarding this?